# Marquee tag start position

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I would like to do is have a marquee start at the top-right-upper corner to up.  Now it starts scrolling from right-bottom corner to up but i have nothing to set for start from there. Is there a way to start scrolling from right-upper corner to up.

```
<marquee  id="news"   onMouseOver="javascript:stop()"  onMouseOut="javascript:start()"  direction="up" behavior="scroll" dir="ltr" height="100%" hspace="10" loop scrollamount=2 scrolldelay=50 >
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think most people would say "don't use the marquee": http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

Comment: The `marquee` element is deprecated, you should not use it. Consider building your own with CSS and JS. We can help.

Comment: @Khez, We have the technology!!  :)

Comment: @Khez - It's not deprecated. It's just never been part of the HTML standard.

Comment: undead http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use marquee.  [This says it all](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee):

```
<marquee>
```

**HTML Reference**

The `<marquee>` element is a non-standard element.

HTML5 classifies it as a [non-conforming feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete).

**Examples**

No, really. don't use it.

Comment: The question clearly asks about the marquee tag, not whether the OP should be using it.